# exclude column from table range for html google app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm using app script to get an HTML page
everything works fine
except that I need to exclude column B+C from the range

```js
function doGet() {
  return  HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate()
  .setTitle("Performance Efficiency");//We can set title from here

}
 
//GET DATA FROM GOOGLE SHEET AND RETURN AS AN ARRAY
 function getData() {
  var spreadSheetId = "Sheet ID"; //CHANGE
  var dataRange = "Data!A3:P"; //CHANGE

  var range = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadSheetId, dataRange);
  var values = range.values;

  return values;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var values = range.values;
```

#### To:

```
var srcValues = range.values;
var temp = srcValues[0].map((_, c) => srcValues.map(r => r[c])).filter((_, c) => ![2, 3].includes(c + 1));
var values = temp[0].map((_, c) => temp.map(r => r[c]));
```

- In this modification, at first, the value of `range.values` is transposed and remove the columns "B" and "C", and then, the values are transposed. By this, the values except for the columns "B" and "C" can be retrieved.

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)